# Get random variable with javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, random, scope

I have multiple local variables containings information about countrires.

```
let sweden = {
  name: 'Sweden',
  capacity: 120,
  common: ['AX8', 'BLL', 'FAV38']
};
let france = {
  name: 'France',
  capacity: 560,
  common: ['BA', 'BLL', 'EXON']
};
```

I need to pick a country at random and display the information. How could that be done?

Thank you!

Comment: Add those variables to an array, generate a random integer between 0 and array.length - 1, select array[randomInteger]

Comment: Those objects shouldn’t be variables, they should be properties of another object instead, i.e. `let counties = {sweden: {`…`}, france: {`…`}}`. Picking one at random would look like `let entries = Object.entries(countries); let [randomCountryName, randomCountryObject] = entries[Math.floor(Math.random() * entries.length)];`.

Comment: countries = [ { name: 'Sweden', capacity: 120, common: ['AX8', 'BLL', 'FAV38'] }, { name: 'France', capacity: 560, common: ['BA', 'BLL', 'EXON'] } ];
console.log(countries[Math.floor(Math.random() * countries.length)])

Answer (score 5):

Use a `countries` object, then use `Object.values` to retrieve an array of all countries, and then get a random country of that array.

```js
const countries = {
  sweden: {
    name: 'Sweden',
    capacity: 120,
    common: ['AX8', 'BLL', 'FAV38']
  },
  france: {
    name: 'France',
    capacity: 560,
    common: ['BA', 'BLL', 'EXON']
  }
}

function getRandom(arr) {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]
}

let randomCountry = getRandom(Object.values(countries));

console.log(`Random country: ${randomCountry.name}`);
console.log('Random country info', randomCountry);
```

`countries` can be an array directly if you will never access a country directly by it's name: `countries.sweden`, this way you can avoid `Object.values`

```
const countries = [{/*..*/}];

let randomCountry = getRandom(countries);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following:

```
sweden.common[Math.floor(Math.random()*sweden.common.length)]
france.common[Math.floor(Math.random()*france.common.length)]
```

Comment: You misunderstood the question. This is not about a random value from each `common` array, but a random country object.